# Query with more than one group by columns, get the row with max value of one column

Tags: sql, oracle

Below is my query . I am extracting total data by month and institute.

```
select to_char(BILL_TRANSACTION_DATE, 'YYYY-MM') as Month,
institution_id as institutions,
Count(*) as total
from bill_tx tx
group by to_char(BILL_TRANSACTION_DATE, 'YYYY-MM'), institution
order by to_char(BILL_TRANSACTION_DATE, 'YYYY-MM') desc
```

in bill_tx table I have one column called version. I want to change the above query to fetch row with max version value .

Actually I want total number of records by bill_transaction month and institution.

Condition is by disctint BILL_REF_NBR or count only one record if more than one version exist.

I tried to add below in query

```
where tx.version =  (SELECT MAX(version) FROM bill_tx b WHERE b.institution_id  = tx.institution_id  and  rownum = 1  group by b.BILL_REF_NBR )
```

But not getting correct data

Below sample data

```
+----+------------+-------------+--------------+---------+
| id |   Month    | institution | bill_ref_nbr | version |
+----+------------+-------------+--------------+---------+
|  1 | 2020-08-01 | child care  | A001         |       1 |
|  2 | 2020-08-03 | child care  | A001         |       2 |
|  3 | 2020-08-04 | child care  | M001         |       1 |
|  4 | 2020-08-09 | child care  | K001         |       1 |
|  5 | 2020-08-09 | child care  | K001         |       2 |
|  6 | 2020-08-04 | infant care | AC01         |       1 |
|  7 | 2020-08-05 | infant care | AC01         |       2 |
|  8 | 2020-08-07 | Playgroup   | PL01         |       1 |
|  9 | 2020-07-07 | infant care | XX01         |       1 |
| 10 | 2020-07-07 | infant care | XX01         |       2 |
+----+------------+-------------+--------------+---------+
```

output should be

```
+---------+-------------+-------+
|  Month  | institution | total |
+---------+-------------+-------+
| 2020-08 | child care  |     3 |
| 2020-08 | infant care |     1 |
| 2020-08 | Playgroup   |     1 |
| 2020-07 | infant care |     1 |
+---------+-------------+-------+
```

Correct my query if it wrong.

Comment: Please tag appropriate database name.

Comment: For `Orange`, the expected output shouldn't be `5  orange    2` instead of `4  orange    2`?

Comment: Here only highest value of the version to be taken, either 4  orange or 5 orange is fine

Comment: The query is *very* different from your sample data. The two don't seem to have anything to do with each other. So, the date is no longer important in the query? And the count isn't either?

Comment: Now I added real sample data. Sorry I don't know how to format in tabular format

Comment: Okay. I've done the formatting for you. I don't understand your example, though. You want to count the rows with the maximum version. Do you mean the maximum version per month and institution or the maximum version overall? I.e. if I add some row with version 3, would all other rows be void or would that only affect its month and institute? And I suppose the 3 for 2020-08 | child care is a typo and must be 2, because there are three rows for version 1 and two rows for version 2 and version 2 is greater than version 1?

Comment: I think this request would be much clearer, f you just removed the unrelated fruit example.

Comment: Thank a lot of formatting. Now removed unrelated example. I tried to explain more. Please let me know if anything is not clear

Comment: I still don't understand. You want one result row per month and institute. But for one month and institute there can rows with different `bill_ref_nbr` and different `version`. You don't want to count all of these, but only some. Now, what exactly is the rule which rows to count and which to neglect? How do you get a total of 3 for 2020-08 | child care? Would the expected result set change, if we added this row: `10 | 2020-07-07 | infant care | XX01  | 3`?

Comment: I want total count by month and institute . For each bill_ref_nbr I have more than one record with different version. I should take count as one if more than one version exist. Basically distinct bill_ref_nbr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated based on your comment.

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4f0269/3)

```
select to_char(BILL_TRANSACTION_DATE, 'YYYY-MM') as Month,
institution_id as institutions,
Count(distinct bill_ref_nbr) as total
from table1
group by to_char(BILL_TRANSACTION_DATE, 'YYYY-MM'), institution_id
order by to_char(BILL_TRANSACTION_DATE, 'YYYY-MM') desc, total desc;
```

Comment: My purpose of query to get total number of records group by institute and month. one of the condition is choose the record with highest version number

Comment: How you have arrived at this output, please explain the logic. 2020-08 child care 3

Comment: Fro example  child care   in the month 2020-08 three bill_ref_nbr : A001, M001, K001. But A001 has two versions, so I should take count as 1(A001)+ 1 (M001)+ 1(K001) So the total for child care in the month 8 is 3. Like that infant care on 8th month has same bill_ref_nbr two version, so count should be 1.

Comment: version based one bill_ref_nbr. I don't know how to add distinct bill_ref_nbr in broup by query. that is why I try to take max version /

Answer (score 1):

With your last request comment it seems you want something completely different. This is what you say in your request:

> I want to change the above query to fetch row with max version value.

And I think: No, you want to *ignore* the version. Because in the comment you say:

> For each bill_ref_nbr I have more than one record with different version. I should take count as one if more than one version exist. Basically distinct bill_ref_nbr

You want to `COUNT(DISTINCT bill_ref_nbr)`:

```
select
  to_char(bill_transaction_date, 'yyyy-mm') as month,
  institution_id as institutions,
  count(distinct bill_ref_nbr) as total
from bill_tx tx
group by to_char(bill_transaction_date, 'yyyy-mm'), institution
order by to_char(bill_transaction_date, 'yyyy-mm') desc, , institution;
```

Answer (score 0):

You want the number of entries per month and institute, but you only want to count rows for the maximum version.

You can get the maximum version with `MAX OVER`. Depending on whether you are talking about the overall maximum version or the maximum version per month and institute or the maximum version per institute you want either

```
max(version) over ()
```

or

```
max(version) over (partition by to_char(bill_transaction_date, 'yyyy-mm'), institution_id)
```

or

```
max(version) over (partition by institution_id)
```

The complete query:

```
select month, institution, total
from
(
  select
    to_char(bill_transaction_date, 'yyyy-mm') as month,
    institution_id,
    version,
    max(version) over () as max_version,
    count(*) as total
  from bill_tx
  group by to_char(bill_transaction_date, 'yyyy-mm'), institution, version
)
where version = max_version
order by month desc, institution;
```

You can achieve the same with your original query by adding either

```
where version = (select max(version) from bill_tx b)
```

or

```
where (institution_id, version) in
(
  select institution_id, max(version)
  from bill_tx b
  group by institution_id
)
```

or

```
where (to_char(bill_transaction_date, 'yyyy-mm'), institution_id, version) in
(
  select to_char(bill_transaction_date, 'yyyy-mm'), institution_id, max(version)
  from bill_tx b
  group by to_char(bill_transaction_date, 'yyyy-mm'), institution_id
)
```

depending again what you want the maximum version relate to.

Comment: Thanks for taking time and give the reply. I tried the above query,  not getting result as expected.

Comment: Because you said you wanted to count the rows with the maximum version, but you don't. I will delete this answer. I have posted a new answer for the new request.